# Create top ten in Numbers

Tags: numbers

I have a table in Numbers that counts the number of times certain text appears in other tables. It looks like this:

| Día | Cantidad |
| --- | --- |
| 1 de enero | 0 |
| 2 de enero | 1 |
| 3 de enero | 3 |
| 4 de enero | 1 |
| 5 de enero | 1 |
| 6 de enero | 0 |
| 7 de enero | 0 |

There is one entry for each day of the year, so 365 entries.

I would like to create a new table with the top five or top ten days with the highest counts.

Would that be possible? What formula would I have to use?

Comment: Have you tried the [pivot table](https://support.apple.com/en-bh/guide/numbers/tan7f62056cf/mac) feature in Numbers?

Comment: That's close to what I wanted, thank you very much @Alper